# Asynchronous call in synchronous method

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

Here is the simple example:

```
public event EventHandler CookinDone = delegate{};

public void CoockinRequest(){
    var indicator = new ActivityIndicator();
    ActivityIndicator.Show("Oooo coockin' something cool");

    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();    
    bw.DoWork += (sender, e) => CockinService.Cook();
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) => {
       indicator.Hide();
       CookinDone.Invoke(this,null);
    };

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Now, everytime I use that method I have to intercept CookinDone event and move on.

```
var cook = new Cook();
cook.CookinDone += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("Yay, smells good");
cook.CoockinRequest();
```

But how can I simplify that by making return type of the method as Boolean and return result upon the Cookin completion?

```
if (CoockinRequest()) MessageBox.Show('Yay, smells even better');
```

if I put there something like `while (bw.IsBusy)` it will screw my ActivityIndicator, freeze the main thread and I feel it would be the lousiest thing to do. There are also some `Monitor.Wait` stuff and some other stuff like `TaskFactory`, but all that stuff seems to be too complicated to use in simple scenarios.

It might be also different in different environments, like some approach is good for WPF apps, some for something else and whatnot, but there should be a general pattern isn't that right?

How do you do that guys?

Comment: Let's see if someone coocks up an answer...

Comment: Consider having a look at the async CTP; it is a sneak peek at how this sort of code will be simplified in C# and VB in the future. If its not going to meet your needs then we'd like to know about that on the async forum. See http://msdn.com/async for details.

Comment: OMG! it's Eric Lippert! I love your blog sir!

Comment: Anybody knows if async CTP is posible to use with MonoTouch?

Comment: Yeah I like it, it reminds me how stupid and lazy I am. I don't know how is it possible that I am still in software development. Everytime I open your blog and read an article I understand how small my knowledge and sadly I don't have any idea how long it will take me to learn to the point when I don't feel so stupid... Maybe I'm genetically made that way - lazy and stupid, but your blog gives me hope

Comment: @EricLippert: Btw I was wondering since you seem to be involved with the async stuff alot in C# 5.0. Isn't async a .net library feature, not a C# one? From C#'s perspective, is this not just creating a new keyword and make sure to call the right pieces of code when it's compiled? Obviously I don't know how all this fits together, but was curious to see how something like async differs from other alternatives like TPL, PLINQ, etc where AFAIK you aren't as involved, as your day to day job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this in .NET 4.  This is actually very much in line with the new async/await functionality coming in the next release of C#.

The Task Parallel Library can be used in .NET 4 to accomplish this today.  You would do this by changing your code to return a `Task<bool>`, so the caller could wait on it (if required), or subscribe a *continuation* on the task which would run when this was complete.

To do this, you'd rewrite the above code like so:

```
public Task<bool> CoockinRequestAsync()
{
    var indicator = new ActivityIndicator();
    ActivityIndicator.Show("Oooo coockin' something cool");

    // This assumes Cook() returns bool...
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(CockinService.Cook);

    // Handle your removal of the indicator here....
    task.ContinueWith( (t) => 
       {
           indicator.Hide();
       }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    // Return the task so the caller can schedule their own completions
    return task;
}
```

Then, when you go to use this, you'd write something like:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var request = this.CoockinRequestAsync();

    request.ContinueWith( t =>
    {
        // This will run when the request completes... 
        bool result = t.Result;

        // Use result as needed here, ie: update your UI

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: gosh, seems to me it makes things even more complicated than just intercepting basic event, no?

Comment: @Agzam: This has the huge advantage, though, of letting you do this from 2 places, and each can handle the results differently.  WIth a single event, it's very tricky to know "which" of the requests is being completed...

Comment: +1. Another advantage to Reed's solution is that it is "await-ready" - in VS2011 you'll be able to change `SomeMethod` to use `bool result = await CoockinRequestAsync();` and `CoockinRequestAsync` won't have to change at all.