# Wrap asynchronous calls with synchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a 3rd party DLL with an asynchronous method that I want to wrap with another method that waits for its result.

I started writing a class to hide the functionality, but now I can't work out how to wait for `Doc.Completed` to be called by the DLL after `this.version.DownloadFile(this)` in `Doc.Download`.

The DLL calls `InitTransfer`, then `OnProgressNotify` a number of times, then `Completed`. `OnError` may be called at any stage, but `Completed` is always called last. I don't care about `InitTransfer`, `OnProgressNotify` or `OnError`.

I have read 
[Asynchronous call in synchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842180/asynchronous-call-in-synchronous-method) and [Turn asynchronous calls into synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124524/turn-asynchronous-calls-into-synchronous) but I don't understand how to apply the answers to this case.

I'm using C# 4.

```
public class Doc : SomeInterfaceFromTheDll
{
  private readonly IVersion version; // An interface from the DLL.

  private bool downloadSuccessful;

  public Doc(IVersion version)
  {
    this.version = version;
  }

  public bool Download()
  {
    this.version.DownloadFile(this);
    return ??? // I want to return this.downloadSuccessful after Completed() runs.
  }

  public void Completed(short reason)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Notify.Completed({0})", reason));
    this.downloadSuccessful = reason == 0 ? true : false;
  }

  public void InitTransfer(int totalSize)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Notify.InitTransfer({0})", totalSize));
  }

  public void OnError(string errorText)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Notify.OnError({0})", errorText));    
  }

  public void OnProgressNotify(int bytesRead)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Notify.OnProgressNotify({0})", bytesRead));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a ManualResetEvent as shown below. There are a few caveats though. The primary one being that this mechanism does not permit you to call `Download()` on the *same* `Doc` instance on multiple threads at the same time. If you need to do this, then a different approach may be required.

```
public class Doc : SomeInterfaceFromTheDll
{
  private readonly IVersion version; // An interface from the DLL.
  private readonly ManualResetEvent _complete = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  private bool downloadSuccessful;

  // ...

  public bool Download()
  {
    this.version.DownloadFile(this);
    // Wait for the event to be signalled...
    _complete.WaitOne();
    return this.downloadSuccessful;
  }

  public void Completed(short reason)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Notify.Completed({0})", reason));
    this.downloadSuccessful = reason == 0;
    // Signal that the download is complete
    _complete.Set();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case the class is used by one thread, and I added a check to make sure `Download()` can only be called once.